# how to hide expand buttons column in Angular ui-grid for grouping grid

Tags: angular, ui-grid

Is there a way to hide the expand buttons column and show all rows initially for grouping grid?[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J15F.png)

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. This isn't a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to hide grouping expand icon is to add following code in your options,

```
treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
showTreeRowHeader: false,
```